# Grails domain class property change is not flagged as Dirty

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a transient method inside of my domain class that will update a property of the class.  When I use this method the class is not marked as dirty and does not save.

```
class Major {
    String code
    String major

    static transients = ['update']

    def update(String newVal) {
        major = newVal
    }
}

Major major = Major.findByCode("ACAA");
major.update("NEW VALUE");
println("Is dirty? "+ major.dirty);  //Is dirty? false
```

When I update the property outside the method it works as expected and I can save

```
Major major = Major.findByCode("ACAA");
major.major = "NEW VALUE";
println("Is dirty? "+ major.dirty);  //Is dirty? true
```

Is there a reason this does not work?

**Grails 3.3.1**

**GORM 6.1.6**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error lies in the update function. It needs to explicitly call the setter like this:

```
def update(String newVal) {
    setMajor(newVal)
}
```

For reference, see the GORM upgrade notes for [the new dirty checking implementation](https://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#_new_dirty_checking_implementation).

Comment: Latecomer: Has this answer ever been correct? I can't remember that setter syntax has ever been an issue. As Grails versions have evolved there is a strong trend: Move database logic to services to be sure they happen inside transactions. Or use `withTransaction`. The `transient` declaration in this example declares a non-existent transient property. I don't expect it interferes with the logic, it's just superfluous.

Comment: This was absolutely the issue for me.  Grails 3.3.10.  I was trying to set a property in an abstract base class.  It wasn't getting flagged as dirty, so it wasn't getting written to the database.  This fixed the issue, but I kind of hate that this was the fix.  The explicit setter shouldn't behave differently than the implicit setter.  Also, for anyone trying to work in an abstract base class, I had to add the @DirtyCheck annotation (which isn't well documented) to the base class as well.

Comment: I believe this is my issue as well, Grails 3.3.11. For anyone coming here with this problem, this solution worked for me. As a bonus, you don't even need to check the value for a change before invoking the setter. If the new value matches the current value, the field is not marked dirty.

Answer (score 0):

That method does not need to be marked as transient. `transient` properties are usually used if you have a method named `getThing()` so it's not interpreted as the property `thing` that would need to be persisted.

Just remove the field from the `transients` list

http://docs.grails.org/3.3.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html

Comment: Even though it doesn't need to be transient, does being transient prevent a method from modifying the object?

Comment: Thanks for that information but it doesn't change the main issue of the dirty flag not being set.  Issue is still there